# What are the most famous (common used) precalculus books and its differences?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request

I'm trying to decide which one to pick up to begin a self study of mathematics. One of the factors is how much content is covered and the amount of associated solved problems the book has.

**EDIT:**

Lets said my goal are go after something like [this course](http://math.mit.edu/academics/undergrad/major/course18/theoretical.html) doing it self studding. Pls, take just the linked course as a way to define goals more than define content. Seem to me that [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1133949010) is a good one, but I really prefer hear someone else opinions before decide.

The existence of collection of exercises with its solutions is a plus due to the self learning constrain ;)

Comment: To a great extent, this is going to depend on what country you're in. Also, the most widely used text may not be the best text for you, since a text often becomes widely used when it offers something for everyone, offends no one (i.e. isn't difficult), and is great for no one.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Lets said my goal are go after something like [this course](http://math.mit.edu/academics/undergrad/major/course18/theoretical.html) doing it self studding. Pls, take just the linked course as a way to define goals more than define content. Seem to me that [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Precalculus-Ron-Larson/dp/1133949010/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) is a good one, but I really prefer hear someone else opinions before decide.

Comment: I first thought that a slightly more comprehensive book by James Stewart might be better for you, but given that you want to "go after" the MIT pure math sequence at some later time, I think Axler's book would be much more suitable for you than what you suggested or the Stewart book: Sheldon Axler, [**Precalculus: A Prelude to Calculus**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0470180722) (2008).

Comment: There is a [2nd edition, 2012](http://www.amazon.com/dp/047064804X) edition of Sheldon Axler's book available. However, there do not seem to be any reviews of the 2012 2nd edition at amazon.com, so you'll want to look at 2008 1st edition for reviews.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Can you give me some reasons regards your suggestion? I mean, in what way your suggestion is tie to the fact that I want "go after" the MIT pure math sequence? Just for knowing... Thanks again. PS. If you reply my question, I could select your reply as The Reply.

Comment: Sheldon Axler is the author of **Linear Algebra Done Right**, a text well known for its no-nonsense readability and which is frequently cited in math StackExchange, so even without looking I knew it would be a good choice for background for someone who intends to eventually study the MIT pure mathematics curriculum. Also, my initial feeling was only strengthened after I looked at the table of contents, some of the amazon preview pages, and the reader reviews at amazon. One of the strengths cited was its use for independent study, which also fits your situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you want to "go after" the [MIT Theoretical Math Option](http://math.mit.edu/academics/undergrad/major/course18/theoretical.html) at some later time, I think Sheldon Axler's [**Precalculus: A Prelude to Calculus**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470180722) (2008) [see [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047064804X) for the 2012 2nd edition] would be a better choice than what you suggested, which was Larson's [**Precalculus**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1133949010).

Sheldon Axler is the author of [**Linear Algebra Done Right**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387982582), a text well known for its no-nonsense readability and which is frequently cited in math StackExchange, and so without even looking at Axler's Precalculus book, I felt sure it would be a good fit for someone who is aiming to eventually study the MIT Theoretical Math Option. Moreover, this initial feeling of mine about Axler's book was strengthened after I looked at its table of contents, at some of the amazon preview pages, and at the reader reviews at amazon (thus far, only the 2008 edition has reader reviews). One of the strengths of Axler's book that I saw mentioned a lot was its use for independent study, which also fits your situation.

Comment: I like Axler's _Precalculus_. My brother has a copy (of the first edition), and I have a copy of his _Algebra & Trigonometry_ (which I think contains almost the same material, reorganized a bit). Axler always seems mindful that he is teaching you something new that you might not understand immediately, while still treating you like an adult. It feels like he knows that you're not just learning this particular math, you're also still learning how to study math. Also, these books contain *worked* solutions to the odd-numbered problems, which is a big deal for some people.

Comment: Also, Axler is not afraid to give you some real-world advice like (paraphrasing) "you mostly just need to remember sine, cosine and tangent", and "you won't really use Cramer's rule so I'm not going to teach it to you".