# Being ready to study calculus

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, reference-request, trigonometry, self-learning

Some background: I have a degree in computer science, but the math was limited and this was 10 years ago. High school was way before that.  A year ago I relearnt algebra (factoring, solving linear equations, etc).  However, I have probably forgotten some of that. I never really studied trigonometry properly.

I want to self study calculus and other advanced math, but I feel there are some holes that I should fill before starting.  I planned on using MIT OCW for calculus but they don't have a revision course. Is there a video course or book that covers all of this up to calculus?  (No textbooks with endless exercises please.) I would like to complete this in a few weeks. Given my background, I think this is possible.

Comment: Maybe "Essential Calculus with Applications" by Richard Silverman? You can look at the table of contents on Amazon to see if it fits your needs (read also customer reviews). It's at a relatively basic level, but if you start from scratch, it's probably better.

Comment: Thanks arbautjc, I was looking for something that covers pre calculus more, i.e. trig, functions, logs, complex numbers and more algebra.

Comment: [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-014-calculus-with-theory-fall-2010/readings/) they suggest "Calculus" Apostol. Much more expensive, but also much more comprehensive. After a quick look ate TOC, it seems to be at the level of first two years in university in France (in scientific studies), and it covers the whole maths courses (I mean the two volumes).

Comment: See my previous comment

Comment: Math, just like riding a bicicle, is learned by _doing_. So the "endless exercises" are an asset. Nobody forces you to do all of them, select some and work them over carefully. Perhaps check out Pólya's clasic "How to solve it", problem solving skills will be indispensable later on.

Comment: I am now looking at Sheldon Axler's books on Algebra and Trig and Prelude to calculus.

Comment: @Mark, I saw your comment, but there are things about all of this in Apostol. It's not at all limited to integration/differentiation. But I admit its price can frighten a bit.

Comment: @vonbrand. Agreed. However, I was disppointed by "How to solve it". Too verbose to my taste, I prefer the classical, brutal exercises (like in Polya & Szego, to stay with the same author) :-)

Comment: I recommend the Sheldon Axler's books that you said you were looking at (see my comments and answer [in this math StackExchange question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309465/what-are-the-most-famous-common-used-precalculus-books-and-its-differences)), along with with the Gelfand School Outreach Program books: Gelfand/Shen, **Algebra**; Gelfand/Glagoleva/Shnol, **Functions and Graphs**; Gelfand/Glagoleva/Kirilov, **The Method of Coordinates**; Gelfand/Shen, **Trigonometry**.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Yes that's where I found it, based on the TOC it is exactly what I am looking for.  I found that the two books everlap so I have chosen Prelude to Calculus.

Comment: Possibly going at cross-purposes with previous comments, I have to say that I usually neglect those authors starting with such a cliché that to learn math you have to have a lot of practice. If the author doesn't believe math is all about concepts I better find someone else who does.

Comment: @Mark, I am in pretty much the same boat. I have selected [Calculus Made Easy (Silvanus P. Thompson)](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/33283) currently almost half way through and I'm satisfied. Think you can't go wrong with this book, besides it would fit your planned span of time. As to the reviewing resources, why you need them? if you need learn trigonometry (for example) just for backup, the book is self-sufficient.

Comment: @JohnS Thanks for that suggestion, I have bought the Axler book (Precalculus: A Prelude to Calculus) and it is exactly what I need. It builds the foundations needed to go on and do calculus. The limited timeframe I mentioned was for pre calculus. I will spend much more time on Calculus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On my first day of college, my Calc III professor began by extending the properties of real numbers to $\mathbb{R}^n$ vector space. At the end of class, I came up to him, very much floored that the words "distributive property" ever made a reappearance in my life, and mumbled something about not being cut out for this and asking for a resource to do a massive review. He pointed simply to homework he just assigned and said, "That will do fine."

This is all to say that learning math is a little like learning English. The best way to improve your vocabulary is to read and look up unfamiliar words, not insist on finishing the dictionary first. Fill in holes when you get to them: the exponent rules comes first with limits and differentiation, then logarithms, then trig properties, and then all of them again with integration. Don't go back to high school, even if it is only a few weeks; you'll do just fine without it.

Comment: Very good. Very astute. Don't try to prepare in advance toooo much for a thing you don't-know-what-is... Rather, arrive there, discover your own needs, and respond _then_, with that information.

Comment: I think this is a great approach, I had been put off, however when I heard people warning, "if you don't have Algebra and Trig mastered you will struggle with Calculus".

Comment: But where do you start?

Answer (score 4):

The [lecture notes](http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/~maths/notes/wchen/ln.html) by William Chen cover the requested material nicely. The [Trillia Group](http://www.trillia.com/) distributes good texts too.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Paul's Online Math notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/) covering algebra-precalculus, calculus and differential equations.

Comment: Thanks, they look good, it doesn't seem to cover Trig though, but I suppose it can be seen elswhere

Comment: @Mark there is a link near the bottom called "Algebra/Trig Review" in addition to the cheat sheets at the top of the page.

Comment: @TylerBailey Ok I see.